# How can i apply a function on a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm using some php functions for security.

```
function whileToArray($qr)
    {
        while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr))
        {
            $data[] = $rs;
        }
        $data = array_map('htmlspecialchars_decode',$data);
        $data = array_map('htmlentities',$data);
        return $data;
    }
```

When i running this code, I get;

```
Warning: htmlspecialchars_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\AppServ\www\bigbeng\classes\get.class.php on line 22
Warning: htmlspecialchars_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\AppServ\www\bigbeng\classes\get.class.php on line 22
```

#### print_r($data):

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [kategori_id] => 1 [kategori_adi] => Spor )
        [1] => Array ( [kategori_id] => 2 [kategori_adi] => Siyaset ) )
```

How can i use these functions with array?

Comment: paste the result of `print_r($data)`  i think `$data` is multidimensional associative array

Comment: You shouldn't keep HTML-encoded data in your database anyway. `htmlencode()` should only be called on your data at the point where you actually want to embed it in HTML.

Comment: @lanzz I'm using htmlspecialchars_decode when printing data.

Comment: Calling `htmlspecialchars_decode()` on your _database_ results shows that you apparently already have your data `htmlspecialchars()`-encoded when you inserted it in your database. This is not a good approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`array_map`](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) works with 1D  array not on multidimensional array. so try with below function

```
function array_map_recursive($fn, $arr) {
    $rarr = array();
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
        $rarr[$k] = is_array($v)
            ? array_map_recursive($fn, $v)
            : $fn($v); // or call_user_func($fn, $v)
    }
    return $rarr;
}
```

then call

```
 $data = array_map_recursive('htmlspecialchars_decode',$data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should move your decoding logic inside the inner `while` loop:

```
function whileToArray($qr)
{
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr))
    {
        $rs = array_map('htmlspecialchars_decode',$rs);
        $rs = array_map('htmlentities',$rs);
        $data[] = $rs;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

This is a *very* incorrect approach though. Your logic assumes that absolutely all data stored in your database is HTML-encoded; IDs, numeric values, timestamps, everything. You should not HTML-encode *any* data in your database, HTML-encoding should be performed *only* when you actually want to embed a value in HTML.